# My /home is unlocated after Boot repair

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, home-directory

OK here the thing...

I wanted a Windows7 install beside my existing Ubuntu 12.04LTS.
So I Googled some and used many wikis to figure it out.

I made some free space for my windows installation on my HDD. After this was done I installed Windows on this free space. 
After the installation was done I booted my Boot repair USB live dongle to fix the grub.
Everything runs fine. 
Both systems are in grub, windows runs and Ubuntu starts... till it cant find my `/home` partition.

I rebooted and started repair boot USB dongle to check the partitions with Gparted... The `/home` is unallocated.

Don't know what to do next, don't want to lose this `/home` content.

Guess its just something with the partition table, I hope it is. Seems that sda3 moved to a new partition. sdb is the usb dongle.
Any ideas or suggestions for me?

[image]

```
fdisk -lu
user@debian:~$ sudo fdisk -lu

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1ebcccc9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    39063551    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        39065598   437198847   199066625    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   *   437198848   437403647      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4       437403648   488394751    25495552    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda5       425340928   437196799     5927936   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2021 MB, 2021654528 bytes
63 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1010 cylinders, total 3948544 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          62     3945059     1972499    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: I've added an answer from what you've said so far, but could you be more specific about the steps you took when you made room for the Windows partitions? There does seem to be unallocated space between  LBA's 39065598 and 425340928. Any messages about trouble making more than four partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I only see one obvious data Linux partition where you must have /. If you had put /home on its own partition perhaps you eliminated it from your disk when you partitioned it for Windows or created the swap partition. In that case I'm sorry, but it's gone unless it was located in part of the disk you haven't reformatted with a Windows partition.

Did you have trouble making all of the partitions and have to use /dev/sda2 in order to create /dev/sda5 for your swap partition?

If /home wasn't in its own partition it may be that something is awry with the mounts your system is doing and you are mounting an ntfs partition over /home, making the data in the /home directory in your root partition invisible. If that's the case you should be able to use:

```
sudo umount /home
```

and the data in the /home directory of your / partition should be visible again.

If that's the case you may find an entry in /etc/fstab you could comment out.